# Ajax function as part of a javascript comparison

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I'm running into an issue with a jquery ajax function not properly returning its results back to a javascript if statement.

Here is the issue, we have a database function that is generating a long string of if/then statements, an excerpt of which is below

```
if(1==1 && (GenericAjaxValidation("System.Yes")=="Y")) {do stuff}
```

The 1==1 is the result of something that happened in the database, so just ignore that bit. The GenericAjaxValidation call is the piece that is giving us issues The javascript function that it calls is below.

```
function GenericAjaxValidation(token) {

    $.ajax({
        type: "Post",
        url: '../FormAjax/GetAjaxValResult',
        data: {TOKEN:token,FormId:formDisplay.FormID,FormLayoutId:formDisplay.FormLayoutID},
        dataType: "json",
        timeout: 30000,
        async:false,
        success: function(obj) {
            result=obj.Object.ReturnValue;
        },
        error: function(obj) {

            return false;
        },
        complete: function(){
        return result;
        }
    });

}
```

The whole process is set up to fire off as part of an onchange event, and we reach the if statement with no issues. If I drop a break point into the jquery ajax function, it processes properly, and returns the "Y" that it is supposed to. However, when I step back out to the if statement, it fails. I looked at it a bit more and realized that it was always treating the result of GenericAjaxValidation as undefined. In fact, to test it, I changed the if statement to test for equality with undefined, and it succeeded.

My suspicion is that while the asynch: false is causing the rest of that single function to wait for the return, it doesn't appear that the if statement is waiting on it, and evaluates without waiting for the actual value. I searched the net for about a half hour on this one trying to find anything that said for sure one way or the other, but my Google-Fu failed me today.

So, my question is this: is there a way to make this work? or does javascript simply not play nice with this process.

Comment: You cannot return from an AJAX call.  You have to do the comparison and your "do stuff" inside the callback.

Comment: Well it's synchronous, so while that's probably a bad idea it could be made to work in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try (untested code):

```
function GenericAjaxValidation(token) {
    var result
    $.ajax({
        type: "Post",
        url: '../FormAjax/GetAjaxValResult',
        data: {TOKEN:token,FormId:formDisplay.FormID,FormLayoutId:formDisplay.FormLayoutID},
        dataType: "json",
        timeout: 30000,
        async:false,
        success: function(obj) {
            result=obj.Object.ReturnValue;
        },
        error: function(obj) {

            result = false;
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

(edit: as @toby pointed out, the `complete` handler is unnecessary and doesn't do anything)

The problem is that `GenericAjaxValidation` wasn't returning anything.  It's the `complete` function that returns.  A return only returns from the immediate function, not the enclosing function, so `GenericAjaxValidation` was just completing without a `return`

To make it more clear, your original code could be written to be functionally equivilent like this (note in this sample and your original code, `result` is a global variable)_:

```
function GenericAjaxValidation(token) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "Post",
        url: '../FormAjax/GetAjaxValResult',
        data: {TOKEN:token,FormId:formDisplay.FormID,FormLayoutId:formDisplay.FormLayoutID},
        dataType: "json",
        timeout: 30000,
        async:false,
        success: onSuccess,
        error: onError,
        complete: onComplete
    });
    //No return statement
}
function onSuccess(obj) {
    result=obj.Object.ReturnValue;
}
function onError(obj) {
    return false;
}
function onComplete(){
    return result;
}
```

As you can see, `GenericAjaxValidation` never `return`s anything.

Comment: could remove the `complete` handler since it's not doing anything.

Comment: Thanks...dur, don't know how I forgot about the variable losing scope. Only change I had to make was removing the complete function altogether.

Comment: @guildsbounty I would also declare `var result` explicitly unless there's a reason you want it to be in global scope.  Otherwise you might get mysterious bugs when you try to use another variable named `result` without declaring it.

Answer (score 4):

The `return` statements are **inside** the "$.ajax()" callback functions. The values won't be returned as the result of your overall function, because it doesn't have a `return` at all.

You could have the callbacks instead set a local variable and then return that, but really you shouldn't do synchronous ajax in the first place.

Comment: I would LOVE to get rid of the synch...unfortunately, that'd mean a rewrite in how this product does its validation generation...which would take weeks, and then months to fully test...so I'm stuck with what I have.

Comment: Well your user community will be stuck with a sluggish and unresponsive website forever :-)

Comment: Well, until we get the next major release out. Which is in the works...what we have so far is inherited code, and we don't have time until release to fix it.

Comment: I understand; I've been there too.  Designing the mechanism to be async isn't really hard but it is indeed kind-of a  basic decision, and one that needs to be made up front.

Answer (score -2):

My suspicion is that jQuery is screwing you over.

I suggest you try removing the jQuery ajax call, and instead put in a regular XMLHttpRequest object. I can guarantee you that it'll work.

jQuery - simplifying things by complicating them! I write my own code and I know ***exactly*** what it does.

Comment: jQuery is doing nothing wrong.  The function calling `$.ajax` isn't returning anything.

Comment: Kolink if you saw this would you still think it's jQuery screwing you over: `function sum( a, b ) {
var c = a+b;
}

var two = sum( 1, 1 );` :)